# Getting a JsonDecodeError on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, json, django, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm setting up a Jupyter Notebook that apply a Machine learning model from the Ibm watson studio API to some datas that are coming from my Postgresql database.

While reshaping the data to be readable by the API, a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)` appeared and I can't solve it.

This is the full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-9d8e7cf98a41> in <module>()
      1 import json
      2 
----> 3 classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', reshaped).get_result()
      4 
      5 print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2))

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/natural_language_classifier_v1.py in classify_collection(self, classifier_id, collection, **kwargs)
    152         if collection is None:
    153             raise ValueError('collection must be provided')
--> 154         collection = [self._convert_model(x, ClassifyInput) for x in collection]
    155 
    156         headers = {}

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/natural_language_classifier_v1.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    152         if collection is None:
    153             raise ValueError('collection must be provided')
--> 154         collection = [self._convert_model(x, ClassifyInput) for x in collection]
    155 
    156         headers = {}

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/watson_service.py in _convert_model(val, classname)
    461         if classname is not None and not hasattr(val, "_from_dict"):
    462             if isinstance(val, str):
--> 463                 val = json_import.loads(val)
    464             val = classname._from_dict(dict(val))
    465         if hasattr(val, "_to_dict"):

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    317             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    318             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 319         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    320     if cls is None:
    321         cls = JSONDecoder

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353         """
    354         try:
--> 355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
    357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Here's the code in my Notebook:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageClassifierV1
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import json

# connect to the database
conn_string = 'host={} port={}  dbname={}  user={}  password={}'.format('119.203.10.242', 5432, 'mydb', 'locq', 'Mypass***')
conn_cbedce9523454e8e9fd3fb55d4c1a52e = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

# select the description column
data_df_1 = pd.read_sql('SELECT description from public."search_product"', con=conn_cbedce9523454e8e9fd3fb55d4c1a52e)

# package phrases into format required by Watson
reshaped = json.dumps({'collection': [{'text' : t} for t in data_df_1['description']]})

# connect to the Watson Studio API
natural_language_classifier = NaturalLanguageClassifierV1(
    iam_apikey='F76ugy8hv1s3sr87buhb7564vb7************'
)

# apply the model to the datas
classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', reshaped).get_result()

# print the results
print(classes)
```

When I comment the `classes` line and I just do `print(reshaped)`, this is the response I'm getting which is the correct format for Watson studio:

```
{
  "collection": [
    {
      "text": "Lorem ipsum sjvh  hcx bftiyf,  hufcil, igfgvjuoigv gvj ifcil ,ghn fgbcggtc   yfctgg h vgchbvju."
    },
    {
      "text": "Lorem ajjgvc wiufcfboitf iujcvbnb hjnkjc  ivjhn oikgjvn uhnhgv 09iuvhb  oiuvh boiuhb mkjhv mkiuhygv m,khbgv mkjhgv mkjhgv."
    },
    {
      "text": "Lorem aiv ibveikb jvk igvcib ok blnb v  hb b hb bnjb bhb bhn bn vf vbgfc vbgv nbhgv bb nb nbh nj mjhbv mkjhbv nmjhgbv nmkn"
    },
    {
      "text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"
    },
    {
      "text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"
    },
    {
      "text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"
    },
    {
      "text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help.

**EDIT**

This is what I just did:

```
reshape = json.dumps([{'text' : t} for t in data_df_1['description']])


print(reshape)
```

This is the result I'm getting:

```
[{"text": "Lorem ipsum sjvh  hcx bftiyf,  hufcil, igfgvjuoigv gvj ifcil ,ghn fgbcggtc   yfctgg h vgchbvju."}, {"text": "Lorem ajjgvc wiufcfboitf iujcvbnb hjnkjc  ivjhn oikgjvn uhnhgv 09iuvhb  oiuvh boiuhb mkjhv mkiuhygv m,khbgv mkjhgv mkjhgv."}, {"text": "Lorem aiv ibveikb jvk igvcib ok blnb v  hb b hb bnjb bhb bhn bn vf vbgfc vbgv nbhgv bb nb nbh nj mjhbv mkjhbv nmjhgbv nmkn"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "lorem sivbnogc hbiuygv bnjiuygv bmkjygv nmjhgv"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "lore  juhgv bnmkiuhygv nmkiuhb mkjiuhb mkjgv mkjhygv nmkjuytfrdc mjhygtfvc mkijuytfc vbnmkjuhygtfv bnmkjuhygtfvc mjhygv mjhgv nmjhuygv bnjhb mnhgv mjhgv njhgv bnjhb njhygvbnjkiuhbhjihbv mjhgbv nmkjhbhnjb njhgv njmkjhbvbh nhgv mbhhnb hjbhu njbhn njb n  jjijh bb jiji bi jiijib bkiijij b hggg."}, {"text": "Lorem uhygfv bniuhgv nmkjuhgv nmkijuhygv mkihv bjijnb bnjib bjinb bnjub vgvg bhgfc nhgytredxc ngtfv mkjuygfcv bnmjuygv mjhgv bnmkjhgv njhgv njgfvc."}]
```

I copied the results and replace the reshape with these datas:

```
#reshape = json.dumps([{'text' : t} for t in data_df_1['description']])

reshape = [{"text": "Lorem ipsum sjvh  hcx bftiyf,  hufcil, igfgvjuoigv gvj ifcil ,ghn fgbcggtc   yfctgg h vgchbvju."}, {"text": "Lorem ajjgvc wiufcfboitf iujcvbnb hjnkjc  ivjhn oikgjvn uhnhgv 09iuvhb  oiuvh boiuhb mkjhv mkiuhygv m,khbgv mkjhgv mkjhgv."}, {"text": "Lorem aiv ibveikb jvk igvcib ok blnb v  hb b hb bnjb bhb bhn bn vf vbgfc vbgv nbhgv bb nb nbh nj mjhbv mkjhbv nmjhgbv nmkn"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "lorem sivbnogc hbiuygv bnjiuygv bmkjygv nmjhgv"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}, {"text": "lore  juhgv bnmkiuhygv nmkiuhb mkjiuhb mkjgv mkjhygv nmkjuytfrdc mjhygtfvc mkijuytfc vbnmkjuhygtfv bnmkjuhygtfvc mjhygv mjhgv nmjhuygv bnjhb mnhgv mjhgv njhgv bnjhb njhygvbnjkiuhbhjihbv mjhgbv nmkjhbhnjb njhgv njmkjhbvbh nhgv mbhhnb hjbhu njbhn njb n  jjijh bb jiji bi jiijib bkiijij b hggg."}, {"text": "Lorem uhygfv bniuhgv nmkjuhgv nmkijuhygv mkihv bjijnb bnjib bjinb bnjub vgvg bhgfc nhgytredxc ngtfv mkjuygfcv bnmjuygv mjhgv bnmkjhgv njhgv njgfvc."}]


classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', reshape).get_result()

print(classes)
```

And I got a successful response this way.. but that's not very a good way to do it. Any solution?

Comment: can you try this `json.dumps({"collection": [{"text" : t} for t in data_df_1["description"]]})`?

Comment: I will try this now, thanks

Comment: I tried but still got the same error

Comment: try this `new_reshaped = json.loads(json.dumps({"collection": [{"text" : t} for t in data_df_1["description"]]}))` and pass this new_reshaped.

Comment: Getting this error now: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` and the traceback pointing towards the `classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', new_reshaped).get_result()`

Comment: By printing new_reshaped I can see that the response is not in json anymore (single quotes) that's probably why I'm getting this second error, any thoughts?

Comment: If you read the source code [here](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/python-sdk/v1.3.4/_modules/watson_developer_cloud/natural_language_classifier_v1.html#NaturalLanguageClassifierV1.classify_collection), it says that collections should be list. Check [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/natural_language_classifier_v1.py) example. Try this `json.dumps([{"text" : t} for t in data_df_1["description"]])` or `json.dumps([{"collection": [{"text" : t} for t in data_df_1["description"]]}])`

Comment: Tried both but still get the same `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: did you read the example (in the link I provided above) where it is working fine?

Comment: I did read it, yes

Comment: can you try to manually change the output of print and re-assign it to another variable and try? Change to the format shown in the example.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean but I tried some thungs and It didn't worked.

Comment: copy the output of the print(reshape) to some editor (notepad/vim), and then add quotes or double quotes, brackets and make it exactly same as given in that example.

Comment: By replacing the `reshape` value in `classes` with this: `[{"text":"How hot will it be today?"}, {"text":"Is it hot outside?"}]` I get a correct response, so the problem is with the datas from the database and not the model itself. And the response id all in single quotes.

Comment: Isn't the output of `json.dumps([{"text" : t} for t in data_df_1["description"]])` is same to what you are changing to?

Comment: Yes it is exactly the same, thats why I'm confuse. And also I just printed the reshape value, copied the results and replaced the reshape value with the results and pass the new reshape and I get a succesful response, so that's very bizarre.. See my updated question for the full example.

Comment: you can check by `print(type(reshape))` in both the cases and see what is the difference.

Comment: ok so for the original `reshape = json.dumps([{"text" : t} for t in data_df_1["description"]])` I get this: `<class 'str'>`. and for the `reshape = 'results'` I get this: `<class 'list'>`

Comment: So I guess the original reshape should be a list right?

Comment: Yes and if you read my above comments, then I had mentioned that the input should be list to the classify_collections() method. Instead of dumps, just keep `[{"text" : t} for t in data_df_1["description"]]`

Comment: It works now! Thank you so MUCH! I really appreciate your help honestly, best of luck in all your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that json.dumps() was returning `<class 'str'>` (json representation) and the input to the classify_collections() required `<class 'list'>`. Hence we don't use json.dumps() here and simply `replace` to double quotes(") for the keys and pass `<class 'list'>` to the function.

```
reshape = [{"text" : t} for t in data_df_1["description"]]
```